# Advanced Filtering in PowerBI Web Visuals Based on Date Slicer and Version Logic

Tags: powerbi, filtering, slicers

I'm working on refining my PowerBI Web visuals and facing challenges with advanced filtering. I've been leveraging a date slicer to present data up to a selected date. However, this approach isn't capturing all the nuances I need.

Here's the original table structure:

```
| ID  | Version | Date       | IsArchived | Other columns... |
|-----|---------|------------|------------|------------------|
| 245 | 1       | 01/15/2023 | false      | ...              |
| 245 | 1       | 03/31/2023 | true       | ...              |
| 245 | 1       | 04/15/2023 | false      | ...              |
| 256 | 1       | 01/19/2023 | false      | ...              |
| 256 | 2       | 02/26/2023 | false      | ...              |
| 256 | 3       | 03/23/2023 | false      | ...              |
| 879 | 1       | 12/01/2023 | false      | ...              |
| 879 | 2       | 01/15/2023 | false      | ...              |
| 879 | 3       | 02/23/2023 | false      | ...              |
```

For instance, if the selected date in the date picker is 02/12/2023, I'd like the table to be filtered as:

```
| ID  | Version | Date       | IsArchived | Other columns... |
|-----|---------|------------|------------|------------------|
| 245 | 1       | 01/15/2023 | false      | ...              |
| 256 | 1       | 01/19/2023 | false      | ...              |
| 879 | 2       | 01/15/2023 | false      | ...              |
```

And for the date 04/01/2023:

```
| ID  | Version | Date       | IsArchived | Other columns... |
|-----|---------|------------|------------|------------------|
| 245 | 1       | 01/15/2023 | false      | ...              |
| 256 | 3       | 03/23/2023 | false      | ...              |
| 879 | 3       | 02/23/2023 | false      | ...              |
```

The goal is to dynamically show versions pertinent to the chosen date while omitting the archived records. How can I achieve this advanced filtering in PowerBI Web?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you update the question to include the filtering logic that is needed. For example, is it "Get the max version of each ID who's date is before or equal to the slicer"